# Plugin for sublime text 2? Exists?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2

Looking plugin ST2 in which this can:

Do U know a Emment (previously version has named ZenCoding).

When u try this example =>

```
div#wrapper>div.someclass>p.class2{text}|c     + tab
```

===>

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="someclass">
       <p class="class2">text</p>
       <!-- /.class2 -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.someclass -->
</div>
```

The difference is that this I use the finished text (Emmet it knows when it write from scratch)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you looking for a plugin that will display the markup you gave when you write `div#wrapper>div.someclass>p.class2{text}|c` and hit Tab?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I need to add at the end of html tags their identifier or class for easier orientation in HTML.